# INTERSECT query in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, intersection, intersect

I have a problem with this query in MariaDB language. I want to do an intersect with the same field but with two values. The problem is that i can't use the **INTERSECT** query.

How can I do it?? I have tried with exists and inner join but it still doesn't work.

```
SELECT nombre 
FROM actores 
WHERE codactor IN ( SELECT actor 
                    FROM participacion 
                    WHERE (titulo,año) IN (SELECT titulo, año 
                                           FROM peliculas 
                                           WHERE director IN (
                                                SELECT coddirector 
                                                FROM directores d 
                                                WHERE d.nombre='Alejandro' 
                                                 AND d.apellido='Amenabar')))

INTERSECT

SELECT nombre 
 FROM actores 
 WHERE codactor IN ( SELECT actor 
                     FROM participacion 
                     WHERE (titulo,año) IN (SELECT titulo,año 
                                            FROM peliculas  
                                            WHERE director in ( 
                                                  SELECT coddirector 
                                                  from directores p 
                                                  WHERE  p.nombre='Pedro' 
                                                   AND p.apellido='Almodobar')));
```

Comment: I dont see and difference between both query. What result you expect to get? After intersect do you need `'('` ? because you didnt close it. So either both query would need be enclosed by `'()'` or neither does.

Comment: Buenas quizá me entiendas mejor en español. Mira tengo al director alejandro amenabar con dos actores (tom cruise y penelope cruz) y a pedro almodobar con solamente penelope cruz. Y quiero que mi consulta saque la intersección, es decir, solamente a penelope cruz. Muchas gracias

Comment: Si hablo español, pero este sitio se debe escribir en `ingles`, de otro modo solo unos pocos te pueden responder. Si quieres puedes usar la versión en español http://es.stackoverflow.com/. Ahora como te dije, no hay diferencia entre esos dos query. Debes proveer Source Data and Expected Output para saber que necesitas.

Comment: Sorry, I have just edit the question, now you can see the difference between them. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try it like this, to check you have all the actors. I have to add codactor in case you have actors with same name.

```
SELECT a.codactor, a.nombre -- add ', *'  to see all columns and test query is ok. 
FROM actores a
JOIN participacion p
  ON a.codactor = p.actor
JOIN peliculas m 
  ON p.titulo = m.titulo
 AND p.ano = m.ano
JOIN directores d
  ON p.director = d.coddirector
WHERE (d.nombre = 'Alejandro' and d.apellido = 'Amenabar')
   OR (d.nombre = 'Pedro'     and d.apellido = 'Almodobar')
```

Then add `GROUP BY` to see which actor are in movies from both directors.

```
GROUP BY a.codactor, a.nombre
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT coddirector) = 2
```

Comment: Are you sure in table `participacion` field `actor` is the FK to `actors` table? doesnt make sense, should be `codactor `.

Comment: Could you explain me why do you use having count distinct coddirector = 2? I don't understand the reason. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Because you have two directors on the `where`. and you want those actor who work with exact those two directors. Some actors will have 0 or 1. You want the 2.

Answer (score 1):

[`INTERSECT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/intersect/) was introduced in MariaDB 10.3.0.

> **INTERSECT**
>
> The result of an intersect is the intersection of right and left SELECT results, i.e. only records that are present in both result sets will be included in the result of the operation.
>
> ```
> (SELECT e_name AS name, email FROM employees)
> INTERSECT
> (SELECT c_name AS name, email FROM customers);
> ```

As for your query you could leave it as is.